# Rails: how to create image thumbnails that expand when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I have a bunch of images that I want to put into my page as thumbnails. Then, when a user clicks on it, it expands in-browser. I've seen this on some other webpages, and I want to know how to implement this. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question right, this can be done in JS easily. Check out the page listed below -- Hope this helps!

http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0):

For generate several sizes of an image you can use:

[The PaperClip Gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

And as [lillix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4123101/lillix) says you can use Fancy Box to archive that effect, [this guide](http://richonrails.com/articles/fancybox-and-rails) it's a great resource if you want to implement this effect using FancyBox.

The PaperClip gem help you to manage and upload images in different sizes in a easy way.